# What's relation between source code of standard ml in github and compiler.tgz?

Tags: sml

In http://www.smlnj.org/dist/working/110.99.3/index.html I can find the compiler.tgz:http://smlnj.cs.uchicago.edu/dist/working/110.99.3/compiler.tgz it seems it's the source code of smlnj,I can find files like cps.sml...

in https://github.com/smlnj/legacy I can get another smlnj source code,and I can build it success,but in this version,I can't find code in compiler.tgz,like cps.sml

I can't understand this,is the compiler.tgz is not used?but it has been listed in the offcial smlnj website.

Comment: None of your links work.  A tgz is just a compressed tar library, like a zip file.

Comment: The stuff in compiler.tgz in the first load is in the `base/compiler` folder in the git repository.  Git is just a better way to package it.